# Integration by parts probability

Tags: integration

Can anyone advise me if the following is correct:

\begin{align}
\int ax^2 e^{-kx} dx &= \int u dv = \int uv-\int v du\\
u &= ax^2 \frac{du}{dx} =2ax  du =2ax dx\\
v &= e^{-kx} dv = \frac{-1}{k} e^{-kx}dx\\
\int ax^2 e^{-kx} dx &= ax^2 e^{-kx} - \int e^{-kx} dx\\
&= ax^2 e^{-kx} + \frac{1}{k} e^{-kx}
\end{align}

Comment: Please enclose the LaTeX in $'s, and don't forget to add the \end{align}!

Comment: I cant workout where the $ signs need to go, are there any tutorial you could suggest?

Comment: It's okay, I've edited it, for now. You can read http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formula is wrong. ∫udv=uv−∫vdu
u = ax^2 dv = e^(-kx).
du = 2axdx   v = e^(-kx)/(-k)

∫ax^2*e^(-kx) = ax^2 * e^(-kx)/2 -∫e^(-kx)*2axdx

Integrate this and you will get the answer. However you may still have to do integration by parts for the second expression

Refer to this site: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/IntegrationByParts.aspx